# installation error phalcon on MAMP or XAMPP on macOS

Tags: macos, xampp, mamp, phalcon

I'm trying to install phalcon on xampp or MAMP on macOS

please tell me how to install correctly phalcon on MAMP(I get the same errors during installation on XAMPP)

i use this tutorial https://madebyextreme.com/insights/how-to-install-phalcon-php-framework-with-mamp-on-osx

please, help me! I use php 7.3.7

errors:

```
./install: line 133: aclocal: command not found
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
mkdir .libs
 gcc -I. -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits/include -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits/main -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/main -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/TSRM -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/Zend -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/ext -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/ext/date/lib -DPHALCON_RELEASE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -mtune=native -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -c /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits/phalcon.zep.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/phalcon.o
In file included from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits/phalcon.zep.c:52:
./phalcon.zep.h:5760:47: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
        ZEND_ARG_OBJ_INFO(0, uri, Psr\\Http\\Message\\UriInterface, 0)
                                                     ^
./phalcon.zep.h:10328:47: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
        ZEND_ARG_OBJ_INFO(0, uri, Psr\\Http\\Message\\UriInterface, 0)
                                                     ^
./phalcon.zep.h:10341:122: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
  ...0, 1, Psr\\Http\\Message\\UriInterface, 0)
                              ^
./phalcon.zep.h:19544:100: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_OBJ_INFO_EX(arginfo_phalcon_url_urlinterface_setbasepath, 0, 1, Phalcon\\Url\\UrlInterface, 0)
                                                                                                   ^
./phalcon.zep.h:19544:105: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_OBJ_INFO_EX(arginfo_phalcon_url_urlinterface_setbasepath, 0, 1, Phalcon\\Url\\UrlInterface, 0)
                                                                                                        ^
./phalcon.zep.h:19556:99: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_OBJ_INFO_EX(arginfo_phalcon_url_urlinterface_setbaseuri, 0, 1, Phalcon\\Url\\UrlInterface, 0)
                                                                                                  ^
./phalcon.zep.h:19556:104: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_OBJ_INFO_EX(arginfo_phalcon_url_urlinterface_setbaseuri, 0, 1, Phalcon\\Url\\UrlInterface, 0)
                                                                                                       ^
./phalcon.zep.h:30753:139: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
  ...0, 1, Phalcon\\Http\\Message\\UploadedFile, 0)
                                  ^
./phalcon.zep.h:30815:129: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
  ...0, 2, Phalcon\\Http\\Message\\Uri, 0)
                                  ^
./phalcon.zep.h:31150:134: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
  ...0, 1, Psr\\Http\\Message\\UploadedFileInterface, 0)
                              ^
./phalcon.zep.h:31241:116: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_OBJ_INFO_EX(arginfo_phalcon_http_message_uri_withfragment, 0, 1, Phalcon\\Http\\Message\\Uri, 0)
                                                                                                                   ^
./phalcon.zep.h:31249:112: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_OBJ_INFO_EX(arginfo_phalcon_http_message_uri_withpath, 0, 1, Phalcon\\Http\\Message\\Uri, 0)
                                                                                                               ^
./phalcon.zep.h:31257:112: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_OBJ_INFO_EX(arginfo_phalcon_http_message_uri_withport, 0, 1, Phalcon\\Http\\Message\\Uri, 0)
                                                                                                               ^
./phalcon.zep.h:31265:113: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_OBJ_INFO_EX(arginfo_phalcon_http_message_uri_withquery, 0, 1, Phalcon\\Http\\Message\\Uri, 0)
                                                                                                                ^
./phalcon.zep.h:31273:114: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_OBJ_INFO_EX(arginfo_phalcon_http_message_uri_withscheme, 0, 1, Phalcon\\Http\\Message\\Uri, 0)
                                                                                                                 ^
./phalcon.zep.h:31281:116: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_OBJ_INFO_EX(arginfo_phalcon_http_message_uri_withuserinfo, 0, 1, Phalcon\\Http\\Message\\Uri, 0)
                                                                                                                   ^
./phalcon.zep.h:31290:112: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_OBJ_INFO_EX(arginfo_phalcon_http_message_uri_withhost, 0, 1, Phalcon\\Http\\Message\\Uri, 0)
                                                                                                               ^
./phalcon.zep.h:31422:116: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_OBJ_INFO_EX(arginfo_phalcon_http_message_urifactory_createuri, 0, 0, Psr\\Http\\Message\\UriIn...
                                                                                                                   ^
./phalcon.zep.h:45839:89: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_OBJ_INFO_EX(arginfo_phalcon_tag_geturlservice, 0, 0, Phalcon\\Url\\UrlInterface, 0)
                                                                                        ^
./phalcon.zep.h:45839:94: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_OBJ_INFO_EX(arginfo_phalcon_tag_geturlservice, 0, 0, Phalcon\\Url\\UrlInterface, 0)
                                                                                             ^
./phalcon.zep.h:47203:87: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_OBJ_INFO_EX(arginfo_phalcon_url_setbasepath, 0, 1, Phalcon\\Url\\UrlInterface, 0)
                                                                                      ^
./phalcon.zep.h:47203:92: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_OBJ_INFO_EX(arginfo_phalcon_url_setbasepath, 0, 1, Phalcon\\Url\\UrlInterface, 0)
                                                                                           ^
./phalcon.zep.h:47215:86: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_OBJ_INFO_EX(arginfo_phalcon_url_setbaseuri, 0, 1, Phalcon\\Url\\UrlInterface, 0)
                                                                                     ^
./phalcon.zep.h:47215:91: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_OBJ_INFO_EX(arginfo_phalcon_url_setbaseuri, 0, 1, Phalcon\\Url\\UrlInterface, 0)
                                                                                          ^
./phalcon.zep.h:47227:92: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_OBJ_INFO_EX(arginfo_phalcon_url_setstaticbaseuri, 0, 1, Phalcon\\Url\\UrlInterface, 0)
                                                                                           ^
./phalcon.zep.h:47227:97: warning: \U used with no following hex digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_OBJ_INFO_EX(arginfo_phalcon_url_setstaticbaseuri, 0, 1, Phalcon\\Url\\UrlInterface, 0)
                                                                                                ^
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits/phalcon.zep.c:8282:9: warning: nonnull parameter 'ce' will
      evaluate to 'true' on first encounter [-Wpointer-bool-conversion]
        while (ce) {
        ~~~~~  ^~
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits/phalcon.zep.c:3061:83: note: declared 'nonnull' here
static int zephir_has_constructor_ce(const zend_class_entry *ce) ZEPHIR_ATTR_PURE ZEPHIR_ATTR_NONNULL;
                                                                                  ^
./php_phalcon.h:73:45: note: expanded from macro 'ZEPHIR_ATTR_NONNULL'
# define ZEPHIR_ATTR_NONNULL __attribute__((nonnull))
                                            ^
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits/phalcon.zep.c:12759:74: warning: format specifies type 'long'
      but the argument has type 'zend_long' (aka 'long long') [-Wformat]
                php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "max(%ld) is smaller than min(%ld)", max, min);
                                                       ~~~                             ^~~
                                                       %lld
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits/phalcon.zep.c:12759:79: warning: format specifies type 'long'
      but the argument has type 'zend_long' (aka 'long long') [-Wformat]
                php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "max(%ld) is smaller than min(%ld)", max, min);
                                                                                ~~~         ^~~
                                                                                %lld
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits/phalcon.zep.c:140546:35: warning: \U used with no following hex
      digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
        ZEPHIR_REGISTER_CLASS_EX(Phalcon\\Url, Exception, phalcon, url_exception, phalcon_exception_ce, NULL, 0);
                                         ^
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits/phalcon.zep.c:140564:36: warning: \U used with no following hex
      digits; treating as '\' followed by identifier [-Wunicode]
        ZEPHIR_REGISTER_INTERFACE(Phalcon\\Url, UrlInterface, phalcon, url_urlinterface, phalcon_url_urlinterface_method_entry);
                                          ^
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits/phalcon.zep.c:140757:65: warning: incompatible pointer types
      passing 'zend_ulong *' (aka 'unsigned long long *') to parameter of type 'unsigned long *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  ...replace = phalcon_replace_marker(1, paths, replacements, &position, cursor, marker);
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits/phalcon.zep.c:140625:89: note: passing argument to parameter
      'position' here
zval *phalcon_replace_marker(int named, zval *paths, zval *replacements, unsigned long *position, char *cursor, char *marker)
                                                                                        ^
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits/phalcon.zep.c:140791:65: warning: incompatible pointer types
      passing 'zend_ulong *' (aka 'unsigned long long *') to parameter of type 'unsigned long *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  ...replace = phalcon_replace_marker(0, paths, replacements, &position, cursor, marker);
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits/phalcon.zep.c:140625:89: note: passing argument to parameter
      'position' here
zval *phalcon_replace_marker(int named, zval *paths, zval *replacements, unsigned long *position, char *cursor, char *marker)
                                                                                        ^
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits/phalcon.zep.c:140817:64: warning: incompatible pointer types
      passing 'zend_ulong *' (aka 'unsigned long long *') to parameter of type 'unsigned long *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                                                replace = phalcon_replace_marker(0, paths, replacements, &position, curso...
                                                                                                         ^~~~~~~~~
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits/phalcon.zep.c:140625:89: note: passing argument to parameter
      'position' here
zval *phalcon_replace_marker(int named, zval *paths, zval *replacements, unsigned long *position, char *cursor, char *marker)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 4.0.0 Phalcon requires the PSR extension. The extension can be downloaded and compiled from [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/jbboehr/php-psr). Installation instructions are available on the `README` file of the repository. Once the extension has been compiled and is available in your system, you will need to load it to your `php.ini`. You will need to add this line:

```
extension=psr.so
```

before

```
extension=phalcon.so
```

Alternatively some distributions add a number prefix on ini files. If that is the case, choose a high number for Phalcon (e.g. `50-phalcon.ini` and `20-psr.ini`).