# Error installing phalcon 4.0.5 on php-fpm-alpine docker

Tags: php, docker, phalcon, alpine-linux

When I try to make custom docker image with php:7.4.4-fpm-alpine and install phalcon 4.0.5 with pecl on it, there is an error on compiling phalcon

```sh
creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: patching config.h.in
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/sh /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultusernGokha/phalcon-4.0.5/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/phalcon -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultusernGokha/phalcon-4.0.5/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultusernGokha/phalcon-4.0.5/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/phalcon -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/phalcon/phalcon.zep.c -o phalcon.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/phalcon -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultusernGokha/phalcon-4.0.5/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultusernGokha/phalcon-4.0.5/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/phalcon -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/phalcon/phalcon.zep.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/phalcon.o
/tmp/pear/temp/phalcon/phalcon.zep.c: In function 'zephir_mt_rand':
/tmp/pear/temp/phalcon/phalcon.zep.c:12795:45: warning: format '%lld' expects argument of type 'long long int', but argument 4 has type 'zend_long' {aka 'long int'} [-Wformat=]
12795 |   php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "max(%lld) is smaller than min(%lld)", max, min);
      |                                          ~~~^                              ~~~
      |                                             |                              |
      |                                             long long int                  zend_long {aka long int}
      |                                          %ld
/tmp/pear/temp/phalcon/phalcon.zep.c:12795:71: warning: format '%lld' expects argument of type 'long long int', but argument 5 has type 'zend_long' {aka 'long int'} [-Wformat=]
12795 |   php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "max(%lld) is smaller than min(%lld)", max, min);
      |                                                                    ~~~^         ~~~
      |                                                                       |         |
      |                                                                       |         zend_long {aka long int}
      |                                                                       long long int
      |                                                                    %ld



^[[A^CMakefile:8: recipe for target 'php_build' failed
```

have any idea about this error? becuase I cannot find any thing on internet and phalcon repo related to this thing, and when I install phalcon on my computer(ubuntu 18.04) everything is ok

Comment: Did you check the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473354/installation-error-phalcon-on-mamp-or-xampp-on-macos ?

Comment: @pduersteler yes, but there is no different :(

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you check the docker files that phalcon has (not sure if they're maintained anymore) and try to imitate what they are doing? Maybe you'll find a hint in them that helps you.

Comment: @pduersteler I will check it .